# Executing multiple linux commands using && in background from a PHP script

Tags: php, linux

Ok so I have a operating system Ubuntu. I have lampp. Now I wanna execute some command in the background which is going to take atleast 10-15 minutes to execute. I want to execute this command from PHP script from web interface not cli.

**First Instance:**

When I do this , the php script is successfully able to run the command in the background:

```
command1 &> /dev/null &
```

**Second Instance:**

But when I do this:

```
command1 &> /dev/null && command2 &
```

,

Then the command does not run in background, the php script pauses until this command executes. I want the command2 to execute after command1 is completed so that I (or my php script) can know that command1 has been executed. But it should be in background else my php script doesn't execute on time.

When I do the second instance from command line, it is able to run in background, but when I do it from php script then it is unable to run in background.

I am using the exec function of php to execute those commands.

```
<?php
exec('command1 &> /dev/null && command2 &',$out,$ret);
?>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried using two `exec` statements, one after the other?

Comment: You may want `&` instead of `&&`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php
exec('(command1 && command2) >/dev/null &',$out,$ret);
```

What it's doing is launching your commands in a subshell so that `command1` runs first and then `command2` only runs after `command1` completes successfully, then redirects all the output to `dev/null` and runs the whole thing in the background.

If you want to run `command2` regardless of the exit code of `command1` use `;` instead of `&&`.

Answer (score 0):

The computer is doing what you're instructing it to do. The [`&&` list operator](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Lists) tells the shell to only run the second command if the first command completes successfully. Instead, you should run two independent commands; if there really is a dependency between the two commands, then you may need to reconsider your approach.